# Определить width каждого элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Добавляю элементы в массив через `push()`.
Пытаюсь перебрать элементы функцией `forEach()`.

```
playlists.push($('.sossage'));
            playlists.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
                console.log(element.width());
            });
```

В результате выдает только длину первого елемента. В зависимости от количества эелементов в массиве выдает такое же количество раз значение длины первого элемента. Где я ошибся?

Comment: Ваш массив имеет один элемент со списком элементов с классом .sossage'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методом push() Вы добавляете в массив playlists только 1 элемент - массив jquery элементов. А Вам нужно добавлять **каждый** элемент в массив playlists отдельно.

```
$('.sossage').each(function(index, el ) {
    var item = $(el);
    playlists.push(item);
});
```

вот рабочий пример http://jsfiddle.net/kwsyak70/

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.